# Why is the 'in' Operator failing

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a function that checks if a web server is up.
I run a wget command then check the result for `200 OK` in the string. I'm using the `in` operator but it keeps failing and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I have posted my code below.

Thanks for reading.

```py
import subprocess

web_address = "reddit.com"
wget = subprocess.Popen(["wget", "--spider", web_address], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = wget.communicate()
response = output.decode('utf-8')
if '200 OK' in response:
    print("its up")
else:
    print("its down")
```

Edit: `subprocess.getoutput()` solved my problem.

Comment: How is it failing? What is your expected result and what result are you getting?

Comment: You should use the [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library to make your web request instead of `wget`.

Comment: @AChampion I'm expecting `its up` to be printed but `its down` keeps being printed.

Comment: Try putting `print(repr(response))` before the `if` statement, to see what exactly it is.

Comment: @Boris why? Probably the OP requires the behavior defined by the `--spider` option. This is not an unreasonable way of getting that.

Comment: What makes you sure that it's the `in` operator that is failing? Please extract a [mcve] to make sure that your findings are repeatable and that your interpretation is accurate!

Comment: @wjandrea it prints `''`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running shell command and capturing the output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760215/running-shell-command-and-capturing-the-output)

Answer (score 0):

`wget` logs all messages to `stderr`, you can capture the `stderr` output using `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` and then check `err`, or you can redirect `stderr` to `stdout` with `stderr=subprocess.STDOUT` and continue using `output`, e.g.:

```
In []:
wget = subprocess.Popen(["wget", "--spider", web_address], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output, err = wget.communicate()
'200 OK' in output.decode('utf-8')

Out[]:
True
```

Or using `check_output()` call:

```
In []:
output = subprocess.check_output(["wget", "--spider", web_address], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, encoding='utf-8')
'200 OK' in output

Out[]:
True
```

Or using `subprocess.run()` (@Boris):

```
In []:
output = subprocess.run(["wget", "--spider", web_address], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, text=True).stdout
'200 OK' in output

Out[]:
True
```

Comment: Since this is python 3, you should use `subprocess.run()` instead of `check_output()`

Comment: You should do `subprocess.run(..., text=True, capture_output=True).stderr`